# encrypt password in ini file in powerbuilder

Tags: encryption, ini, powerbuilder

I am working in powerbuilder IDE is it good idea to encrypt a value in `inifile` or encrypt the entire file in order to protect user id and password ?

Comment: Protecting passwords in .ini files is more about stopping prying eyes of coworkers than hackers. I have an example of using the Microsoft Crypto API from PowerBuilder:  http://www.topwizprogramming.com/freecode_crypto.html

Comment: this example is not working in powerbuilder 11.5v

Answer (score 1):

**Encrypting passwords within text files** appears to be an acceptable practice in the IT industry. It is also common to find encrypted passwords stored as a column in a database.

**I have not heard of encrypting the entire file** and the reason it's probably not done is that you'd end up with a file name with unsupported characters for the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently rewrote the crypto api example so it should work better.